# Generating flat landmasses with bounds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I am wondering how I can select `gameObjects` in groups randomly so they form landmasses.

Since I already have them laid out in the hierarchy, all I really need to do is figure out how to randomly select these `gameObjects` in groups shaped like landmasses, since it would be unnecessary to create multiple different maps manually.

There are exactly 2500 `gameObjects` that are children of one `gameObject`, named Ground.

I don't really know if this question is too vague. Please tell me if it is so, I'll be glad to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As i got - You have 2500 objects as child of one parent object and want to select n objects randomly from them?

1. Declare an Gameobjects array and integers array of size n
2. Generate n random numbers but number do not exceed from 2500 and save them in integers array through loop
3. For child use naming convention like "Child1 or _1Child" any thing you like but some integer at end or start to match with randomly generated numbers.
4. Find Parent Object using something like `Find() or FindGameObjectWithTag()`
5. Find Child objects in parents transform using loop like `parent.transform.Find("Child"+randomly_generated_values);`

Comment: I do want to select randomly from them, but I also want those to be selected so they form landmasses. Is this possible? And if so, how would this work?

Comment: Make an parent object of landmasses or assign numbers only to landmasses objects. Use different patron for there naming.